# Removed PCI graphics, now onboard graphics no "Windows" but works fine BIOS & Linux

Tags: windows-vista

Removed a graphics card from machine that dual boots Windows Vista & Ubuntu.

When using onboard graphics, the machine boots & works flawlessly in Ubuntu with the new HDTV.

However, after the GRUB menu, Windows does not show anything yet it boots because the hard drive light is stable after activity & when I do a hard reset, it asks me how to boot Windows (safe mode, command prompt, etc.)

Any thoughts or suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting into Safe Mode or VGA mode.

If you can get Windows to boot either way remove your PCI graphics drivers and install whatever is appropriate for your on-board video.  If you can't uninstall the drivers in Safe Mode then try VGA

Comment: Thanks, should have stated yes, I am able to boot into Safe Mode. I'll try that option and see if I can post my results. Thanks in advance